# Getting 'you do not have rights to publish collection' error message

Tags: content-hub

In one of my Asset collections, I assigned `Manager` access level for one user group.

However, when I am trying to access this collection using one of the the user that belongs to the user group, it is showing me the option of "share collection link". When I click on this, I am getting an error "You do not have rights to publish collections".

What could I be missing?

See the screenshots for references
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`publishcollection` is a privilege that is required to be able to publish collections.

Please check your user group has this privilege assigned on the **Privileges** tab.

Manage-> Users -> User groups (then user group policies -> Privileges tab)

Comment: That worked !! Thank you..